# Qual é a função do getch(); e da biblioteca conio.h?

Tags: c

Para que serve a função `getch();`?

Para que serve a biblioteca `conio.h;` qual é a utilidade?

Por exemplo num código tipo este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world");
    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Essa biblioteca está considerada obsoleta

Comment: A princípio, esta função captura um caractere da entrada e retorna. Porém, ela é mais usada mesmo para "pausar" o terminal.



Normalmente, quando se faz um programa que só imprime algo no terminal, o Windows abre uma janela do `cmd.exe`, executa o programa e logo em seguida fecha a janela.


Para impedir este comportamento, costuma-se usar a função `getch` da conio. Assim, o sistema aguarda uma entrada do usuário, a qual será descartada (pois o valor de retorno de getch não será usado), e depois disso o programa segue normalmente.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O `getch()` como também o `getche()` retorna a tecla digitada, muito usado em menus com switch.(Diferença entre os dois é que o `getch()` não mostra a tecla que digitou na tela, já o `getche()` mostra na tela qual foi a tecla digitada)

Arquivos com extensão `.h` não são bibliotecas, mas arquivos de cabeçalho onde, entre outras coisas, se encontram os protótipos das funções utilizadas.

`conio.h` é para desenhar tela, e é para dos/windows (as funções do conio são úteis para manipular caracteres na tela, especificar cor de carácter e de fundo.)

Agora você deve estar se perguntando:

Mas quais funções eu poderei usar com `conio.h` e qual a relação com o `getch()`?

As funções tipicas utilizadas com o `conio.h` são **`clrscr`**(para limpar a tela), **`gotoxy`**(posiciona o cursor na tela nas coordenadas x e y), **`getch`**(lê um carácter do teclado e não o mostra na tela), **`kbhit`**(testa se alguma tecla foi apertada, é necessário usar o comando **`getch`** ou **`getche`** antes), **`delline`**(apaga a linha que contem o cursor e move todas as linhas abaixo dela uma linha para cima), **`textcolor`**(muda a cor do texto),  **`textbackground`**(muda a cor do fundo), **`cprintf`** (utilizada para imprimir na tela textos coloridos, é necessário especificar a cor usando a função textcolor).

No caso do seu código o emprego do conio foi por causa do emprego do `getch()` que é o maior responsável pela utilização  da biblioteca. Os outros comandos geralmente você pode usar o comando `system()` que irá utilizar comando DOS para as mesmas finalidades.

Comment: Uso o DEV C++ e quando coloco o conio.h algumas outras funções (clrscr e gotoxy) não funcionam, o que poderia ser?

Comment: Preciso ver o código pra poder ajuda-lo, faça uma pergunta no site e eu responderei =). Sem ver o código não sei o que pode estar errado. (mas por sugestão se estiver programando em windows pode usar o system("cls");, dependendo da aplicação você poderá usa-lo mas não é recomendável se for usar em tipos diferentes de SO. Por isso é melhor fazer uma pergunta no site)

Comment: @WellingtonTellesCunha há também o chat da comunidade https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha